# I would like to display hashmap data one by one using foreach?

Tags: java

i want to display a hashmap but via key and one td per value instead of the whole lot in one? heres what i mean :

```
                    String getDescription = rs.getString("description");
                    int level = rs.getInt("level");
                    Timestamp startDate = rs.getTimestamp("startDateTime");
                    Timestamp endDate = rs.getTimestamp("endDateTime");
                    String LessonId = rs.getString("lessonid");
                    this.less = new Lesson(getDescription, startDate, endDate, level, LessonId);

                    putDescriptions.add(less.description);
                    putStartTime.add(less.startTime);
                    endTime.add(less.endTime);
                    List list = Arrays.asList(less.date.split("2010"));
                    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                        putDates.add(list.get(i).toString());
                        Level.add(less.level);
                        LessonID.add(less.ID);
                        this.lessons.put("description", putDescriptions);
                        this.lessons.put("StartDate", putDates);
                        this.lessons.put("StartTime", putStartTime);
                        this.lessons.put("EndTime", endTime);
                        this.lessons.put("Level", Level);
                        this.lessons.put("LessonID", LessonID);
```

//above is bean code

jstl :

```
      <c:forEach var="temp" items="${sessionScope.AvailableLessons['description']}">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <td>
                                    <c:out value="${temp}"/>
```

Comment: AkashKing you want to display `HashMap` key `per row or per colummns`, meaning `per tr or per td`

Comment: i want to display hashmap value per td yes thats right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should be sufficient,

1.) Loop should be outside, but inside your `table tag`.

2.) Inside `for each` loop, open `tr or td` as per your need.

```
<c:forEach var="myVar" items="${myMap}">
    ${myVar.key} ${myVar.value}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: i tried this: <c:forEach var="temp" items="${AvailableLessonBean.lessons}">
                        <form action="" method="POST">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <c:out    value="${temp['description']}"/>
                                </td>